# How can I completely hide elements that overflow their container vertically?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a fixed width and height container that consists of arbitrary height elements that need to be stacked vertically. How can I hide any elements that do not fit? `overflow: hidden` could still show the part of an element that doesn’t overflow.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  background-color: #ccc;
  line-height: 54px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
}

.incorrect {
  background-color: #fa9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">show</div>
  <div class="box">show</div>
  <div class="box incorrect">hide</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Meta discussion on this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348251/2065702)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Assuming that your child elements have the same width as the container, this can be achieved by leveraging the containing box created from the [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex?v=control) property.

The trick is to use `flex-flow: column wrap;` in conjunction with `overflow: hidden;` on the container. The former dictates that the content is stacked vertically and that anything that does not fit should be wrapped into a second column, outside of the content box of the container. The latter dictates that this second column (and any subsequent columns) should be hidden.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}
.box:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mind that it will also hide other stuff, in my case a `filter: drop-shadow` which overflows

Comment: Also, if any focusable content inside it, you can tab to it and put it in view.

Answer (score 5):

An easy way of doing this would be to use CSS `columns` instead of `flex`.

Just use a `column-width` equal to the width of the container. Apply `break-inside: avoid` on child `div`s. And there you go.

It resolves all of the asks:

> [..]have a fixed width and height container that consists of arbitrary
>   height elements that need to be stacked vertically. How can I hide any
>   elements that do not fit?

You can notice that the red div (the last one) is hidden completely.

**Example Snippet:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.container {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  height: 200px; width: 300px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  column-width: 300px; 
}
.box {
  padding: 8px; text-align: center; color: #fff;
  width: 250px; height: 80px;
  break-inside: avoid
}
.box:nth-child(1) { background: #3b3; }
.box:nth-child(2) { background: #33b; width: 200px; height: 75px; }
.box:nth-child(3) { background: #b33; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">show</div>
  <div class="box">show</div>
  <div class="box">hide</div>
</div>
```

**Note:** As of now, Firefox is still a problem area with CSS columns. The `break-inside`, although [documented on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside), is buggy in Firefox. The bug is still open: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=549114.

Answer (score 1):

The [OP`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43547431) is beautiful, but the first item will still be clipped, instead of hidden, if it does not fit.

If you want the first item to become hidden as well, you can use a spacer with the relevant dimension set to zero.

Here's the idea, applied to a row, just for some variation:

(note the `.container` can be resized for some live action)

```css
.container {
  /* functional */
  height: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* cosmetic & convenience */
  background-color: plum;
  width: 10em;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.container div {
  /* functional */
  height: 100%;
}

.container div:first-child {
  /* functional */
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>
    <!-- zero-width spacer -->
  </div>
  <div>first</div>
  <div>second</div>
  <div>third</div>
</div>
```