# Hide tags that overflow container and show extra tags react + tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a div that can have many children(tags for an entity) in this example.

If the tags overflow the container, I want to show a small badge indicating the number of tags hidden due to overflow.

I did some research, and I found [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547430/how-can-i-completely-hide-elements-that-overflow-their-container-vertically#:%7E:text=The%20trick%20is%20to%20use,content%20box%20of%20the%20container.) to hide it, although I couldn't find anything to count the number of overflowing "child" elements.

```
<div className="flex items-center gap-x-1 mt-2 tag-list" ref={containerRef}>
      {tags.length ? (
        tags.map((tag, i) => {
          const { bgColor, text } = getColor(color, i);

          return (
            <div
              className={`py-1 px-2 bg-${bgColor} text-${text} rounded-lg text-[10px]`}
              key={i}
            >
              {tag}
            </div>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <div
          className={`py-1 px-2 bg-${color}100 text-${color}800 rounded-lg text-[10px]`}
        >
          No Tags
        </div>
      )}
</div>
```

Here's an example of the overflowing element:
[image: Example]

If you notice, after "A" all elements overflow. I need to hide overflowing elements and show the number of hidden elements(in this case 5).

Comment: Hi, please show the code you have, so others can help to modify it

Comment: Hi Akash, please share the code